# How to setup a cloud development setup for parallel development?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ide, sublimetext3, sftp, development-environment

### I want to setup an cloud development environment for my personal use.

Requirements:
1. Have a cloud web server (basically any linux system) serving my Elixir (backend language) app.
2. Connect Sublime Text / Atom to this server (via sftp maybe), and make code changes and save. Automatic compilation and other stuff will be taken care by mix or task runner.
3. Multiple device connectivity to this setup.

## Reasons for this setup:

1. I want to be able to develop from anywhere (office, home, etc), just configure the IDE and continue to work from where I left off last from any device.
2. Better productivity and less setup required.
3. Secure as well

## Current solution I have:

1. Had setup a linux instance with sftp server enabled.
2. Created projects under the root of the sftp directory.
3. Run task runners in those projects to auto compile and server with other stuff.
4. Connected sublime text to this sftp server and start working. On save it uploads the file to the server.
5. I connect another laptop to this server and can start working on last saved state.

This setup works fine till now, but if there is a better way for this, I would love to know.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use a cloud VCS like github to host your code?

Comment: Git will be used and pushed to github as well. I want to have one copy of the code instead of multiple copies on same number of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using git, you don't need a separate cloud server for syncing your dev environments. The easiest way to meet your needs would be to create a branch in git called `workinprogress` (for example), and then push and pull to it from your various locations. When you have something you want to publish to the main branch you can do an interactive rebase before merging, which enables you to rewrite the history of your `workinprogress` branch, squashing and rewording the commit messages as much as you like. Then once you have everything you want on the main branch, you either delete `workinprogress` and start a new one, or just `git checkout workinprogress && git reset --hard master`.

If you still want to have your Elixir app on a live server somewhere, then you can just pull from Github on that server and get latest updates for the app.

I work from various places too, and use this work flow. No problems so far.